# How to add css to google map marker?

Tags: javascript, css

In google map marker I can do this.The customization happen in icon:[] but I want to custom it in the css file.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,

  map: map,
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8.5,
    fillColor: "#ff0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWeight: 0.4,

  },
})
```

but what if I want to do the css style like this to animate the marker. In html I can do the class='classname' and go to css to set .classname but in javascript I don't know how to .

```
.marker {
margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.pulse {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #ffb3b3;

    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}

.dot {
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: -25px;
    left: -25px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 10px solid #ffe6e6;;
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    -webkit-animation: flash 2s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: flash 2s ease-out;
    animation: flash 2s ease-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }

 @-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {-moz-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0.0;}
 25% {-moz-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0.1;}
 50% {-moz-transform: scale(0.1);opacity: 0.3;}
 75% {-moz-transform: scale(0.5);opacity: 0.5;}
 100% {-moz-transform: scale(1);opacity: 0.0;}
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes "flash" {
 0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0.0;}
 25% {-webkit-transform: scale(0);opacity: 0.1;}
 50% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1);opacity: 0.3;}
 75% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);opacity: 0.5;}
 100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1);opacity: 0.0;}
}
```

Is it possible to add css to javascript and how ?
my full code : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XQEiuQJkBHnO2fX9hDWApfMtwTCYZpDq

here is the result I want it to be.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wArrz.png)

Comment: Can you post full code please and a fiddle/codepen of what you're stuck on, not what you want?

Comment: already edit and update sir @jdmdevdotnet